# Drift of Madgwick algorithm and MPU9250 sensor?

Tags: arduino, magnetometer, imu

For my project i need a way to determine correct orientation of the rocket.

I took code for Madgwick filter from here

```
https://github.com/morgil/madgwick_py
```

for collecting data i used Arduino Nano + MPU9250 sensor. This setup sends packets every 12ms to my PC via Serial.

I calibrated magnetometer by calculating biases to "align" axis origin and center of sphere, created by set of measurements.

Then i drew coordinate axis with blender:
[3D axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjSwg.png)
and coded some script for it. It just reads values from serial, feeds them into Filter, and then rotates my axis object using quaternion rotation mode.

I screwed up with orientation of X axis a little bit, so when i rotate my board clockwise, axis on the screen rotates counter-clockwise. I flipped signs of all X components, and it became fine.

According to this picture [Axis of MPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4emM3.png) i flipped X and Y axis and sign of Z axis, to align axis of magnetometer with gyroscope + accelerometer

And it almost works with one small exception - when after "stabilization" i tilt i.e. X axis downwards (or Y axis, doesnt matter) this axis starts drifting toward global X-Y plane. If i tilt axis upwards, remaining axis starts drifting around global O-Z axis, like this
[X Axis downwards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ8uL.png)
[X Axis upwards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCmLt.png)

Speed of that drift depends on Beta of Madgwick filter - the more beta the more drift.

What can be done there?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: By error and trial I found best combination for the beta and the number of iterations (multiple runs of the algorithm on one received measure). But I think this is not supposed to work like this. Maybe 9250 is inaccurate, or maybe I should transfer faster than 1 packet every 12ms, but I'm going to figure it out.